# Regex selecting by exclusion

Tags: regex

```
("<?xml version=\"1.0\" standalone=\"yes\"?>  <DATAPACKET Version=\"2.0\" version dada Version
```

Let's say I have this sample text and I want to select only the `version` or `Version` words which are **not** preceded by the `xml` and `DATAPACKET` tags.

So far I have:

```
((\<?xml |\<DATAPACKET )(v|V)ersion)
```

which selects the ones that I don't want to see. How do I go from here to selecting the other ones

with `(\<?xml |\<DATAPACKET )?[v|V]ersion`
I can select all of the items, both needed and the ones that do not qualify, but I need to somehow exclude the 2 selections which have the tags part.

Comment: What flavor/language are you using ? Notes: **1-** you don't need to escape `<` **2-** `(v|V)` == `[vV]`

Comment: I'm actually trying to find something in VisualStudio in a cpp document using the built in search of the IDE.

Comment: Which version of VS? Regex implementations vary wildly between 2008 and before vs. 2010 and after.

Comment: I'm afraid then you're out of luck. VS has only been supporting lookbehind assertions (which you need here) since version 2010.

Comment: [strike]You can search for all of them and then filter out the ones you don't need. With your second regex you only need to check the first match group to know if the match is relevant or not.[/strike] Oh, now I see your comment regarding the IDE. Then of course, you can try to find the relevant info as follows: `[^xK][^mE][^Tl].[vV]ersion`

Comment: @TimPietzcker I can load the part of the code in notepad++ and try there. I'm not using the search in coding, I just want to find the bloody hardcoded value from some recording. It just happens to be in a C++ file, but it might as well be any text.

Comment: @Matthias That will "eat" and match unwanted characters or won't work at all in some cases...

Comment: @HamZa I know, that's why I said "you can *try* to find..." ;-) If other options are not available, I would try it out and see if it hits the relevant places.

Comment: the problem is that those tags repeat ... quite a lot (over 10k lines of that) and finding the ones that I don't need would take a lot of time.

Comment: Notepad++ won't cut it. You need an editor with better regex capabilities, for example (if you can't afford the Pro version which I *highly* recommend) [EditPad Lite](http://www.editpadlite.com/).

Comment: Or maybe I'm overcomplicating things. You only want to exclude those `version`s that are *directly*  preceded by `<?xml ` or `<DATAPACKET `? That might even work in Notepad++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following (in Notepad++):

```
(?<!<\?xml\s|<DATAPACKET\s)\b[vV]ersion\b
```

This only works if there's exactly one whitespace character before `Version`; that's a limitation of the regex engine that Notepad++ uses.

In Visual Studio 2010 or higher, that limitation is removed:

```
(?<!<\?xml\s+|<DATAPACKET\s+)\b[vV]ersion\b
```

would work there.